# Data model for geo spatial data and multiple queries

Tags: mongodb

I have some mongodb object let's call it `place` which contains geo information, look at the example:

```
{
   "_id": "234235425e3g33424".
   "geo": {
             "lon": 12.23456,
             "lat": 34.23322
          }
   "some_field": "value"
}
```

With every `place`, a list of features is associated with:

```
{
  "_id": "2334sgfgsr435d",
  "place_id": "234235425e3g33424",
  "feature_field" : "some_value"
}
```

As you see features are linked to places thanks to `place_id` field. Now I would like to find: list of `features` connected with nearest `places`. But I would like also add search contition on `place.some_field` and `feature.feature_field`. And what is important I would like to limit results.

Now I am using such approach:

1. I query on `places` with condition on `geo` and `some_filed`
2. I query on `features` with condition on `feature_field` and `place_id` (limit only to ones found in 1.)
3. I limit results in my application code

My question is: is there better approach to such task? Now I cannot use mongo `limit()` function, as when I do it on `places` I can end with too few results as I need to make second query. I cannot `limit()` on second query as results will come up with random order, and I would like to sort it by distance.

I know I can put data into one document, but I presume that list of `features` will be long and I can exceed BSON size limit.

Answer (score 0):

Running out of 16mb for just the features seems unlikely... but it's possible. I don't think you realize how much 16mb is, so do the maths before assuming anything!

In any case, with MongoDB you can **not** do a query with fields from two collections. A query always deals with one specific collection only. I have done a very similar thing than what you have here though, which i've described in an article: http://derickrethans.nl/indexing-free-tags.html — have a look at that for some more inspiration.